# If I create an atomic variable are all operations on the variable atomic between threads?

Tags: c, multithreading

Would this code work properly?
What is the difference between atomic_int vs _Atomic(int)

```
  struct a {
    int xyz;
    volatile _Atomic(unsigned int) status;
    int eee;
    };

    threadOne(void *)
    {
    a->status |= QW;
    }


    threadTwo(void *)
    {
    a->status |= ER;
    }
```

Comment: As [shown in the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic), `atomic_int` is a typedef for `_Atomic int`. As for 'working properly' - it won't crash if that's what your asking. Be specific.

Comment: Do I have to use atomic_load and friends for stores the be thread safe?

Comment: Yes and no. An `atomic` variable is **guaranteed** to be thread safe. There are however tons of alternative ways to achieve that, for example with mutexes and semaphores. Win32 API has some atomic operations as well on the OS level. Also, in practice, in any modern system, operations involving a normal `volatile int` are atomic by definition, just not 'guaranteed' (so yes, bad practice to rely on that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work properly, i.e. the `|=` operations will be atomic

As far as where things are defined (this is more than you asked for):

- `_Atomic` is defined by C11 (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic))
- `atomic_int` is defined in C11 as a typedef to `_Atomic int` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic)).
- `std::atomic_int` is defined in C++11 as a typedef to `_Atomic int` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic)); on MS you might have [some problems](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/720151)
- `atomic_int` outside of the above is (I think) also an MS thing
- `atomic_t` is defined by the linux kernel (see [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/atomic_ops.txt) and [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/types.h#L178))
- `sig_atomic_t` is defined by the GNU C Library and others (see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Atomic-Types.html))